Why does my LC tank not change the frequency according to the LC formula?
The following is my circuit schematics.

The LC tank oscillator should be oscillate around 100 MHz when cap is 20pF. However, it's around 400 MHz in real life measurement. Even though I switch to 2.2nF cap, the frequency is still around 370MHz.
According to LC tank formula.
$$f_{osc} = \frac{1} {2 \pi \sqrt{L C} }$$
When the Cap increase 1000 times, the frequency should be \$\frac{1} {\sqrt{1000}}\$ times of the original as well.
My board in 3D. I used 6 layer PCB for better shield with ground and power plane pour.

The inductor I used.


Measurement through Rigol oscilloscope.
Probe is 100 MHz.

The frequency is also measured in Zedboard with AD-FMCOMMS3-EBZ.


Was C9 (0.1uf) meant to go to Vcc ? Seems to connect to T2 collector (Q2C).

So you have a perfect $C=20:\text{pF}$ and $L=125:\text{nH}$ for your tank? How much analysis of your board parasitics have you done? Also, if you are measuring a much higher frequency, then your methods for measurement are in question. Or else something else on that board is oscillating and you aren't recognizing where it is coming from. Given the factor of 1000 change in capacitance, I think you are simply measuring something else and need to work on that, first.

@periblepsis I use oscilloscope with 8GSa/S (MSO5104), and then I use SDR (software defined radio) to crosscheck the FREQ. L C are not perfect, that 's why I put the datasheet of the inductor.

@periblepsis Attenuation will be great for oscilloscope with 100MHz bandwidth, but it's not bad for frequency check.

@kile Well, you don't get 370 MHz from 2.2 nF and the inductor you are pointing at. Sorry. Doesn't happen. And with 5-10 nH per inch on the board (at a wild guess) and other trace capacitances I can't guess at, what do you suggest might be the source of such a high frequency? (Outside RF interference interacting with the board?) I'm certainly not going to be able to help. Not only am I ignorant. But I'm also lacking all the data you have in front of you. Just wanted to ask you to take the blinders off and start looking around, more. I don't think it is your tank.

What kind of probe are you using with your oscilloscope? And can you post a screenshot showing the waveform with frequency measurement?

@pion Probe is 100MHz. For peak to peak is not accurate because attenuation is too great. But frequency should be ok. See my latest update on the post.

The collector of T2 is more or less shorted to ground through C9 (100nF). The 100MHz collector tank circuit is thus made redundant. Instead of the intended common base you now have something similar to a common collector Colpitts socillator.
Because of the subpar layout, especially in the RF section, you introduced unintentionally, among other things, an inductor (10..20nH) in series with the transistor base that now determines, together with C6 and transistor parasitics, the oscillation frequency. It is very likely that the RF stage will now oscillate somewhere in the UHF region.
Btw. a 6-layer pcb is imho complete overkill for such a simple circuit. A 2-layer pcb, maybe even a 4-layer pcb if you feel generous, would already be perfectly acceptable.

Any suggestions on RF layout? What kind of changes should I make here? Do I need 3D EM wave simulation for this PCB?

No 3D EM sim needed. Main problem is C9 connected to the wrong place. Many people seem to forget that the wires connecting all the components together in the schematic have zero length. You have to adhere to that in the layout, especially in critical places around T2 with associated components C4, C6, C7, tank circuit, C9 etc. The circuit looks like something found somewhere on the internet. Have you checked that it works like intended?

I removed C9 with hot air gun. However, the frequency remained unchanged.

@kile I'd add a 1nf capacitor from Vcc to GND, close to the point where L1 joins Vcc. Although the board itself has some inherent capacitance between Vcc & GND, it may not be enough. Removing C9 was a good move.

C9 is just one of many problems. C9 should be used for decoupling the tank circuit to ground like initially intended. The problem is you don't have any easy access to ground because you connected the copper pour on top to VCC. Why did you do that? Put a 1nF cap directly from the transistor base to GND (in your case try VCC instead). Solder C6 directly between collector and emitter. Remove C7 for now. With all the long traces between the components there is no guarantee that the oscillator will work.

The reason I use VCC pour on top is that I want better shield for high speed signal.
Do you  mean I should remove VCC pour?

You don't have high speed signals. I don't see how connecting the copper pour on top to VCC would help shield high speed signals. Large copper areas on top and bottom should be GND. Inner layers are a different story.

Should add cap between Emitter and antenna coaxial (J1 in my schematic) to remove DC?

Yes. For a 50 Ohm load/antenna put a small capacitor with a few pF in between.
