Can I use the same equation for microstrip when ground plane is replace with VCC plane?
In 4 layer stack-up PCB, the bottom side is usually the signal which has VCC/Power plane instead of ground.


In typical setup, we use ground plane in most illustration. And the equation goes like below.

Is this still equation valid when ground plane is replaced with  power plane?

Yes, it is the same.
However your signal will pick up 'noise' from the VCC line, and this needs to be considered in your application.

I used VCC  coplanar in my previous FM design. But I calculate the impedance to be 50 ohm  for coplanar . However, even though I did impedance matching, i still failed to achieve FM frequency.

I'd also add you need to make sure your terminations (source and load) have paths to ground if needed.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/724099/why-does-my-lc-tank-not-change-the-frequency-according-to-the-lc-formula

@kile you'll have to explain why the transmission line Z0 had an effect on the FM frequency.

@ThePhoton My freq is between 350 Mhz and 400 Mhz. I tried different cap for my LC tank, it looks like that it only change amplitude instead of Frequency. I believe there is some sort of parasitic from PCB which I haven't considered

@jp314 What value of decoupling cap do you suggest for VCC and Ground?
